# mPDF: How to use CSS to control layout?

Tags: mpdf

I'm using mPDF with PHPExcel. I'm trying to configure layout with CSS. I can't get anything to work.

```
// this has no effect
$pdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('color', '#ff0000');
```

I also try to use external style sheet:

```
// in php
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('pdf_styles.css');
$pdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);

// in pdf_styles.css
body {
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 5pt;
    color: red;
}
```

Any help or hint would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put your CSS directly into your template, that works for me.
In you template add sth like this in the head part:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
   // all your styles come here
   body {
     font-family: serif;
     font-size: 5pt;
     color: red;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>

... all your other stuff comes here

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im trying to convert a dynamically created phpExcel object to PDF, not a HTML file...

Comment: but you use `WriteHTML()` which means, that you actually write some HTML into mPDF. So you should also be able to add some styles. Could you maybe add some more code on how you do it? Or maybe just try ti write the `<style>` part of my suggestion with `WriteHTML()`. It may also work this way.

Answer (score 0):

you have to be very exact in your css usage.
for example does mpdf not accept this:

```
border-bottom: 1px #000000 solid;
```

this isnt prohibitted by browsers but mpdf needs this:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
```

specfic informations can be found here:
http://www.plogin.net/mpdf/mpdf/docs/example_css.php

i use an external css file which i include like this into my template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pdf.css">
```

so there is no need to use any inline css.